Input suggestions for multiple fields on the bottom of the page
I'm currently designing a UI for a mobile-first project. What I currently have is a setup, where there are two input-fields on the bottom of the page. Those input fields need auto-suggestions.
I was wondering how those can be done to look nice. Ideally I don't want to just "above and center", as editing the lower field would block out the upper one. Does anyone have suggestions?


What's wrong with your current approach?

This totally depends on the use case of your application.
If you have only two edits, there is not much you can do in arranging them.
If you do not need to have both visible all the time, you can provide only one input field and two buttons above where you can switch between "Input A" and "Input B".
But again, totally depends on the nature of the app. This cannot be inferred from the current information you gave.
